# Incompatible types. Required java.util.List<Object> found java.util.List<Integer>

Tags: java, list

I need to use a List of Lists for an Android project in Android Studio, but anytime y try to declare one I get this error highlighted. I have tried to make a cast, I tried to use generics and almost everything,but every time I get this error highlighted. 
Here's an example of one type of code that sends this error:

```
List<List<Object>> p = Arrays.asList(
                Arrays.asList(1,2,3)
        );
```

The weirdest thing is that in IntelliJ this code works perfectly fine. So, I would like to know how to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use generics, you could declare the List this way:

```java
List<List<? extends Object>> p = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```